# how to use crontab -c @reboot to autostart redmine

Tags: linux, crontab, redmine

I have installed a Redmine on CentOS 7, I can run the Redmine application by manually execute the command of `cd /var/www/html/redmine && bundle exec rails server webrick -e production -b 192.168.1.109 &` but I want to set above command can be automatically executed when the contos startup.so the Redmine can be automatically started in when I reboot my CentOS 7.

I have tried put above command into `crontab -e as *@reboot`

`/var/www/html/redmine && bundle exec rails server webrick -e production -b 192.168.1.109 &*`

but it wasn't worked,and I used the shell,it was also faied.
I really want to know how to rewrite the `crontab -e` to startup my redmine automatically when I reboot my CentOS 7.

Comment: It's probably better to use systemd to start and monitor services. It was designed for this purpose.

Comment: @mtak how to use systemd to automatically  execute the command of cd /var/www/html/redmine && bundle exec rails server webrick -e production -b 192.168.1.109 & ? could you tell me? thanks!

Comment: It's not that hard. Please do some research and if you can't figure it out, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup uses Ruby's `webrick` webserver. An alternative would be to serve it from an `apache` server. E.g. see [this link](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/How_to_Install_Redmine_on_CentOS_%28Detailed%29).

Comment: @mvwthanks for your link.but I'm using contos7,do you have a instructor for contos7?

Answer (score 0):

Redmine start ON reboot. Working for me:

```
crontab -e
```

add to end this line:

```
@reboot cd /home/redmine && passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -d -e production >/home/redmine/startup.log 2>&1
```

/home/redmine - change to your directory (Log file directory aswell)